# Is it possible to order the intensity of Esperanto adjectives?

Tags: word-usage, adjectives

Esperanto has a **lot** of ways to modify the intensity of adjectives. Even ignoring *pli* and *plej*, the following possible levels of intensity of *bona* exist: *bona*, *boneta*, *bonega*, *tre bona*, *tre boneta*, *tre bonega*, *ege bona*, *ege boneta*, *ege bonega*, *treege bona*, *treege boneta*, *treege bonega*. If we include *pli* and *plej* as modifiers, then the number of possible levels goes up to 36.

I doubt few Esperantists would actually use all of these forms; they add a little variety, but introduce ambiguity¹. But they are possible, whether or not someone dares to use them. Is there an accepted way to order them by intensity?

<sub>¹For example: what do *tre boneta* and *treege boneta* mean? "Very somewhat good" vs. "Extremely somewhat good"?</sub>

Answer (score 4):

*Boneta*, *bona*, and *bonega* are (theoretically) different concepts. *Boneta* means "good in a small way", i.e. "fairly good", and stands in relation to *bona* in the same way that *beleta* ("pretty") stands to *bela* ("beautiful"). Similarly, *bonega* can be understood as "not just good, but on a superior level" which is why it is translated as "excellent".

Thus, *tre boneta* means "very good in a small way"—like a bad poem which has been very careful versified, or a bad painting displaying a high level of technique, or (if you'll indulge me) an armed robber who just got out of prison who always offers visitors a cup of tea and a slice of cake.

Apart from that, it seems reasonably clear that the sequence *tre, ege, treege* is increasing in intensity.

Zamenhof touches on this in one of his *Lingvaj Respondoj* from 1908.

> (EO) Tute prave vi diras, ke la sufikso *eg* ne povas servi por simpla anstataŭado de la vortoj “granda” aŭ “tre”, sed ĝi devas servi por kreado de vortoj *novaj* kun senco *speciala*. Tia neĝusta uzado de la sufikso certe ne estas aprobinda, kaj, kiom oni povas, oni devas ĝin eviti. Tamen esti *tro* severaj en ĉi tiu rilato ni ankaŭ ne devas. En multaj okazoj, en kiuj ni povus bone uzi la vortojn “granda” aŭ “tre”, ni povas ankaŭ sen peko kontraŭ la spirito de Esperanto uzi la sufikson *eg*, ĉar tre ofte la saman ideon unu persono povas prezenti al si kiel ideon simplan en granda mezuro, dum alia persono ĝin prezentas al si kiel ideon *specialan*. Ekzemple, la vorton “bonega” ni preskaŭ ĉiam povus anstataŭigi per “tre bona”, kaj tamen en la samaj okazoj oni ankaŭ povas prezenti al si bonecon *eksterordinaran* kaj uzi por ĝi vorton *apartan* tiel same, kiel oni faras preskaŭ en ĉiuj lingvoj.
>
> (EN) You are quite correct to say that the suffix *eg* cannot serve as a simple replacement for *granda* or *tre*, but must serve to create *new* words with *special* meanings. That sort of incorrect usage of the suffix [in which *tre* and *granda* are systematically neglected] cannot be approved of, and one should avoid it as much as possible. However we must also avoid being *too* severe on that question. On many occasions, when we could well use the words *granda* or *tre*, we could also without sinning against the spirit of Esperanto use the suffix *eg*, for very often the same idea may be presented by one person as a simple idea taken to an extreme, and by another person as a *special* idea. For example, the word *bonega* we can nearly always replace with *tre bona*, and nevertheless in the same situations we can also think of ourselves as meeting with extraordinary *bonecon*, and use a separate word, just as one does in nearly all languages.